# Failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource with custom cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

Updated:  Apologies, had a copy / paste issue - code is now shown as it exists - with ALL of the returns...

---

Generally, I can figure this out with all of the great existing examples. Happy to update with any other information you may need.

Objective:
Create a UITableViewController which has 2 sections.  In the upper section, I want to display a custom-classed row which provides switch-based settings.  On the lower section, I want to provide a list of items to select - again, using a custom-class.

All cells and links were created in the storyboard

Problem:
It compiles fine, but during runtime it fails with:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {375, 88}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource ()'
>   First throw call stack:

What I have tried:

1. Using breakpoints, I have watched it roll through numberOfSections, and numberOfRowsInSection.
2. I have tried to use a breakpoint to check the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but the exception is thrown before the function is called.
3. Broken, and re-connected links, checked identifiers, re-validated everything I know to do.

Classes and screen shots are as follows:

---

### Class for cell with Switches

[CellWithSwitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcZeX.jpg)

```
import UIKit

class CellWithSwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameSwitch: UISwitch!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

---

### Class for cells with selection

[CellWithSelect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6PB4.jpg)

```
import UIKit

class CellWithSelectTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }
}
```

---

### TableViewController:

```
class MapOptionsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var mapOptions = MapOptionsAvailable()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // return the number of sections
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var returnValue = Int()

        if section == 1 {
            returnValue = 1  

        } else if section == 0 {

            returnValue =  1 
        }
        return returnValue
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("Entered cellforRowAtIndexPath.  Row",indexPath.row,"Section",indexPath.section)

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellWithSwitch", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CellWithSwitchTableViewCell
            cell.nameLabel.text = "Name of switch"
            cell.nameSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)

            return cell

        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellWithSelect", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CellWithSelectTableViewCell
            cell.nameLabel.text = "Name of Selection"

            return cell


        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if I can furnish any additional info.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` will not compile (and is pretty cumbersome).

Comment: Ah ya, missing an actual return there.

Comment: @ BrandonShega - Thanks.  copy / paste error on my part - the return does exist.  I've updated the code to accurately reflect it.

Comment: @BrandonShega - Yes, using a storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Should have seen this before.

Change old syntax:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

To new Syntax:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

Voila!!